# QML Rich text editor

Tags: qt, qml, rich-text-editor, qtquick2

Is it possible to create simple rich text editor only using QML components?

I'm trying now to do that with `TextArea` but it looks it have no ability to work with formatted text. Sure, I can do something like this:

```js
ToolButton {
 text: "Bold"
 onClicked: {
     var start = textArea.selectionStart;
     var end = textArea.selectionEnd;
     var text = textArea.getText(start,end);
     text = "<strong>" + text + "</strong>";
     textArea.remove(start,end);
     textArea.insert(start,text);
 }
}
```

But I still cannot detect text formatting under cursor.

I'll be glad if anybody can share some code snippet or something.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: `But I still cannot detect text formatting under cursor.` -> Can you elaborate on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Usually, when you click anywhere in a text editor, you can get text format under cursor. For example, you can check `Bold` button if selected text is bolded.

Comment: Have you considered using a WebView?  There's plenty of existing rich text editors in HTML/Javascript that might meet your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure I can embed some JS editor to QML application. Currently (in same c++ app) I use HTML editor to edit HTML templates for printing reports. Is it possible to load from/save to file HTML source in web editior? Inserting images? As I know JS of QML is limited and most of JS libraries not works with it.

Comment: Anything that works in a WebKit based web browser should work the same in a WebView.  WebKit comes with its own Javascript interpreter, it doesn't use the same one as QML.

Answer (score 2):

Oк, аfter searching all the Internet :) I've get to conclusion that it is impossible for now to do a rich editor with only QML.
It can be easy done with C++ and there is nice example in $QTDIR/Src/qtquickcontrols/examples/quick/controls/texteditor/

Comment: you are wrong, it's not impossible. You can do a lot in full qml. Just look at my example.

Comment: ok, let's say you have this HTML in your editor: `<span style="font-family:Tahoma">string1</span><span style="font-family:Arial">string2</span>`. You click on `string2`. How can you get from your example what font name you have to highlight in font combobox? Suppose, you have font combobox in toolbar

Comment: from my example you can't. But you can use the event onSelectionChanged, and use regExp to detect the surrounding block

Comment: Ehm ... you say my example is wrong although it's work like a charm. You propose very difficult solution instead of elegant one with C++.
And you vote down my answer although it is the only way to do rich editor in QML.

Comment: Yes, I know, your solution work perfectly well, but it doesn't answer your question : "Is it possible to create simple rich text editor only using QML components?". It is possible.

Comment: No, it's impossible if only you dont't want to rewrite WebKit in QML. I want to see you parsing HTML with regexp. What about nested tags? External css?

Comment: For people who would like to know how to edit rich text from QML, read this answer. Not sure why it got downvoted. BlueMagma's answer,that in principle one could reproduce all the functionality of a rich text editor from scratch in qml, is not helpful for someone like me who actually NEEDS this functionality. Do a little investigation before downvoting, people.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the **TextEdit** component :

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html

Using it, it should not be hard to implement a Rich Text Editor only with QML

QtQuick TextEdit and by extension QtQuick.Controls TextArea in Qt 5.2 or higher expose the 'textDocument' property which is a QQuickTextDocument pointer, which in its turn can be casted to a QTextDocument (yes, the same as in QWidgets) and it can be used C++-side to get information from the TextEdit such as cursor position and current block format...

Yet for simple EDITING (no information retrieved), pure JS in QML-side could be sufficient (just modify the text property to insert HTML tags using e.g. RegExp...).

Comment: You know, I can't find any difference between TextEdit and TextArea. Same properties, same methods. And both of them, unfortunately, have no tools to build simple rich editor.

Comment: @folibis: you know, in QtQuick Controls examples, there is a port of the QtWidgets Text Editor demo, using the TextArea, so it's obviously feasable !